# Imported shapefile with projection issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have a shapefile which was created under CRS EPSG:27700 in one project and all lines align with basemap (Google satellite EPSG:3857), but when exported into a new project with same basemap the lines have shifted northwards even though the layer remains in EPSG:27700.

How can I fix this issue so they align in my new project without having to edit all my lines by hand?

Using QGIS

Comment: which software are you using

Comment: Is it the same machine? Probably a missing transformation file

Comment: The original project was created on a different laptop, but opened on mine looks aligned properly. It's when I then export the layer and open it in my project that the lines have shifted. I have tried playing around with transformations in the project properties but when done in the original project it shifts them out of place, and when done in my project no changes are made.

Comment: Why are you exporting the layer, rather than just using the same shapefile in each project

Comment: Can you post a before and after of the shift?

Comment: There is crucial information missing from your question, e.g. what does "have shifted northwards" mean exactly? Shifted how much? A few Meters? Hundreds of km? You should add the very steps of your workflow and post screenshots that show the situation. Otherwise, every answer would be just guesswork.